# Sending Email in iOS and Android without using the default/built-in app in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm trying to send any message error in my IOs/Android app to my email but I'd like to send the message directly, **without** showing the default app. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect directly to a SMTP server and send the mail using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.  Or you could setup a webservice to act as a mail relay, and connect to the service from the mobile client.